# Perl CTRL-D equivalent in PHP?

Tags: php, perl, ctrl

I'm trying to represent the following Perl line in PHP:

```
$msg="!<connect_nettapi>\cD";  # Message ends with CTRL+D
```

I'm sending this string over a socket and the receiving API requires that the command be terminated by the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> character. I've been trying to use:

```
$msg="!<connect_nettapi>" . chr(some_hex_code);  # Message ends with CTRL+D
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the EOT character (end of transmission).
It's ASCII value is 4.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip the call to `chr` you can use a hex escape in your string

```
$msg="!<connect_nettapi>\x04";  # Message ends with CTRL-D (hex 04)
```